# Help with clip function in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, technical-drawing

I would like to extend the gray area to x=4.5 with the semi-circles not colored. The problem is how to clip the correct arcs. I tried to use a "for all" command and define multiple arcs but wont work. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxlow}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxhigh}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myiterations}{12}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[-latex](\myxlow-0.1,0) -- (\myxhigh+0.2,0);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\succofmyxlow}{\myxlow+0.5}


    \begin{scope}   
        \clip (\myxlow,0) rectangle (\myxhigh,1.1);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\myiterations}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow+1/pow(2,floor(\i/3))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{pow(1/3,\i-1}
            \foreach \x in {-2,\mysecondelement,...,6}
            {   \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(0:180:\myradius);
                \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius);
            }   
        }
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \clip (-0.5,0) rectangle (4.5,3.0);
            \clip   (1,2.5) -| (-1,0) arc (180:0:1) -- cycle;
          %  \clip   (3,2.5) -| (1,0) arc (180:0:1) -- cycle;
            \fill[gray,opacity=0.8] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,3);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And this is the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update according to [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426074/help-with-clip-function-in-tikz/426080?noredirect=1#comment1066050_426080), which just need to remove one of the clipping paths (the red one):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxlow}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxhigh}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myiterations}{12}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[-latex](\myxlow-0.1,0) -- (\myxhigh+0.2,0);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\succofmyxlow}{\myxlow+0.5}


    \begin{scope}
        \clip (\myxlow,0) rectangle (\myxhigh,1.1);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\myiterations}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow+1/pow(2,floor(\i/3))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{pow(1/3,\i-1}
            \foreach \x in {-2,\mysecondelement,...,6}
            {   \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(0:180:\myradius);
                \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius);
            }
        }
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \clip (-0.5,0) rectangle (4.5,3.0);
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow + 3}
            \clip
                (-1, 3)
                \foreach \x in {-1,\mysecondelement,...,6}
                { -- (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius)}
                -- (4.5, 3) -- cycle
            ;
            \fill[gray,opacity=0.8] (-1,-1) rectangle (4.5,3);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Original version

The following example runs the loop for the half circles twice as clip paths.
Since only the largest half circles are of interest, `\i` is 1 in the clip paths. That simplifies the formulas. The first clip path loop starts with the half circles at -2, the second clip path at -1. Increment is 2.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxlow}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxhigh}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myiterations}{12}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[-latex](\myxlow-0.1,0) -- (\myxhigh+0.2,0);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\succofmyxlow}{\myxlow+0.5}


    \begin{scope}
        \clip (\myxlow,0) rectangle (\myxhigh,1.1);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\myiterations}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow+1/pow(2,floor(\i/3))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{pow(1/3,\i-1}
            \foreach \x in {-2,\mysecondelement,...,6}
            {   \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(0:180:\myradius);
                \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius);
            }
        }
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \clip (-0.5,0) rectangle (4.5,3.0);
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow + 2}
            \clip
                (-1, 3)
                \foreach \x in {-2,\mysecondelement,...,6}
                { -- (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius)}
                -- (4.5, 3) -- cycle
            ;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow + 3}
            \clip
                (-1, 3)
                \foreach \x in {-1,\mysecondelement,...,6}
                { -- (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius)}
                -- (4.5, 3) -- cycle
            ;
            \fill[gray,opacity=0.8] (-1,-1) rectangle (4.5,3);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Visualization of the clipping paths:

```
\draw[cyan, line width=2mm]  % instead of \clip for the rectangle
\draw[red, line width=2mm]   % instead of \çlip
\draw[green, line width=2mm] % instead of \clip
opacity=0.4 % instead of opacity=0.8 for he gray rectangle
```

> [image: Visualization of the clipping paths]

Comment: Another very good answer. +1.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is nice but I should be more specific in my description and I apologise for it. I want the dark region to cover also the "cones" between circles. This is what we get in fundamental groups of congruence subgroups of the SL(2,Z) group. So the "cone" between 0.5 and 1.5 should also be gray (in my picture I achieved half of it only). Same for the cone (1,5,1) to (2,5,1) etc

Answer (score 3):

I think you almost got it in your question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxlow}{-2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxhigh}{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myiterations}{12}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[-latex](\myxlow-0.1,0) -- (\myxhigh+0.2,0);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\succofmyxlow}{\myxlow+0.5}


    \begin{scope}   
        \clip (\myxlow,0) rectangle (\myxhigh,1.1);
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\myiterations}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysecondelement}{\myxlow+1/pow(2,floor(\i/3))}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{pow(1/3,\i-1}
            \foreach \x in {-2,\mysecondelement,...,6}
            {   \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(0:180:\myradius);
                \draw[very thin, blue] (\x,0) arc(180:0:\myradius);
            }   
        }
    \end{scope}


    \begin{scope}
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \clip (-0.5,0) -- (-0.5,3) -- (4.5,3) -- (4.5,0)
            -- (5,0) arc(0:180:1) -- (3,0) arc(0:180:1)  -- (1,0) arc(0:180:1) 
            --cycle; 
            \fill[gray,opacity=0.8] 
            (-0.5,0) -- (-0.5,3) -- (4.5,3) -- (4.5,0) -- cycle;
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{scope}
    \node at (2,2.5) {fundamental domain};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Added something above the circles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah, I did not know how to make those clips :s

Comment: I accepted your answer! sorry, i forgot it earlier!

Comment: I try to create a node somewhere in the gray area (to write an equation) but I fail. Every node, no matter where I put it, goes to the x axis below. Why is that?

Comment: @Marion I added a counter example. Of course you can write equations.

Comment: I was using the command: \node[] (2,1) {x+1}; and would not work as this!

Comment: @Marion Huuh? There is an `at` missing, try `\node[] at (2,1) {x+1};` or better `\node[] at (2,1) {$x+1$};`. And put it *after* the scope, just like in my update.